# Bootstrap affix - Logo does not re-appear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

My code-snippet: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MwBngMJ6JZ)

When I scroll down I want to hide the big logo and display the small logo.
When I scroll up again I want to hide the small logo and display the big logo.

But when I scroll back up again, the big logo does not re-appear.
In the contrary, the small logo is shown whenever it is needed.

What exactly is wrong and how do I fix it so I can switch between both logos when scrolling down and up again?

It does not work in Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera.

Comment: it works for me in firefox..

Comment: It does not in Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera :(

Comment: this is quite a weird situation, if you open "Inspect Element" in Chrome and other browsers, when you scroll down and up, does it emit errors? please paste them

Comment: No.. :( The console stays white with no errors.

Comment: I solved it... I just hade to put both image classes into ONE affix div, instead of seperating both.